# How to fit frailty survival models in R

Tags: r, survival

Because this is such a long question I've broken it down into 2 parts; the first being just the basic question and the second providing details of what I've attempted so far.

## Question - Short

How do you fit an individual frailty survival model in R? In particular I am trying to re-create the coefficient estimates and SE's in the table below that were found from fitting the a semi-parametric frailty model to this dataset [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lYua3GPo9E65WdVoCl5n_C1r_ibCmNKP/view). The model takes the form:

```
h_i(t) = z_i h_0(t) exp(\beta'X_i)
```

where `z_i` is the unknown frailty parameter per each patient, `X_i` is a vector of explanatory variables, `\beta` is the corresponding vector of coefficients and `h_0(t)` is the baseline hazard function using the explanatory variables **disease**, **gender**, **bmi** & **age** ( I have included code below to clean up the factor reference levels).
[image]

## Question - Long

I am attempting to follow and re-create the [Modelling Survival Data in Medical Research](https://www.crcpress.com/Modelling-Survival-Data-in-Medical-Research-Third-Edition/Collett/p/book/9781439856789) text book example for fitting frailty mdoels.  In particular I am focusing on the semi parametric model for which the textbook provides parameter and variance estimates for the normal cox model, lognormal frailty and Gamma frailty which are shown in the above table

I am able to recreate the no frailty model estimates using

```
library(dplyr)
library(survival)
dat <- read.table(
    "./Survival of patients registered for a lung transplant.dat",
    header = T
) %>% 
    as_data_frame %>% 
    mutate( disease = factor(disease, levels = c(3,1,2,4))) %>% 
    mutate( gender = factor(gender, levels = c(2,1)))

mod_cox <- coxph( Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease   ,data = dat)
mod_cox
```

however I am really struggling to find a package that can reliably re-create the results of the second 2 columns.  Searching online I found this table which attempts to summarise the available packages:

[image]
[source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/frailtyEM/vignettes/frailtyEM_manual.pdf)

Below I have posted my current findings as well as the code I've used encase it helps someone identify if I have simply specified the functions incorrectly:

**frailtyEM** - Seems to work the best for gamma however doesn't offer log-normal models

```
frailtyEM::emfrail(
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + cluster(patient), 
    data = dat ,
    distribution = frailtyEM::emfrail_dist(dist = "gamma")
)
```

**survival** - Gives warnings on the gamma and from everything I've read it seems that its frailty functionality is classed as depreciated with the recommendation to use coxme instead.

```
coxph( 
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + frailty.gamma(patient), 
    data = dat 
)
coxph( 
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + frailty.gaussian(patient), 
    data = dat 
)
```

**coxme** - Seems to work but provides different estimates to those in the table and doesn't support gamma distribution

```
coxme::coxme(
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + (1|patient),
    data = dat
)
```

**frailtySurv** - I couldn't get to work properly and seemed to always fit the variance parameter with a flat value of 1 and provide coefficient estimates as if a no frailty model had been fitted. Additionally the documentation doesn't state what strings are support for the frailty argument so I couldn't work out how to get it to fit a log-normal

```
frailtySurv::fitfrail(
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + cluster(patient),
    dat = dat,
    frailty = "gamma"
)
```

**frailtyHL** - Produce warning messages saying "did not converge" however it still produced coeficiant estimates however they were different to that of the text books

```
mod_n <- frailtyHL::frailtyHL(
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + (1|patient),
    data = dat,
    RandDist = "Normal"
)
mod_g <- frailtyHL::frailtyHL(
    Surv(time, status) ~ age + gender + bmi + disease + (1|patient),
    data = dat,
    RandDist = "Gamma"
)
```

**frailtypack** - I simply don't understand the implementation (or at least its very different from what is taught in the text book). The function requires the specification of knots and a smoother which seem to greatly impact the resulting estimates.

**parfm** - Only fits parametric models; having said that everytime I tried to use it to fit a weibull proportional hazards model it just errored.

**phmm** - Have not yet tried

I fully appreciate given the large number of packages that I've gotten through unsuccessfully that it is highly likely that the problem is myself not properly understanding the implementation and miss using the packages. Any help or examples on how to successfully re-create the above estimates though would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your question is only about how to use R, which package, what code, etc., then it is off topic here. This is a big question, it may not get much response on [SO]. You might do best on r-help. Let me know if you want me to migrate this to SO.

Comment: Hi @gung , Indeed I think it is unlikely I will get a reply on SO which is why I posted here as I assumed that the more statistically oriented users here will have a much higher chance of knowing the answer or being able to help. If you are still adamant that this is off topic then yes please can you transfer it to SO; if I do not get any replies there I will try and reach out to r-help as you have suggested.

Comment: Do you have the *Survival of patients registered for a lung transplant* data available? Look into survival's `?survreg` where you supply a *distribution*.

Comment: Hi @Parfait,  I have updated the question to try and clear it up and also attached a direct link to the download the dataset.  Thank you for the suggestion; `survreg` though is focused on fitting parametric models, the equivalent in the survival package for semi-parametric models is `coxph`  but the frailty component seems to be classed as depreciated in favour of  the `coxme` package  which I wasn't able to get to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding

> I am really struggling to find a package that can reliably re-create the results of the second 2 columns.

See the [Survival Analysis CRAN task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html) under *Random Effect Models* or do a search on [R Site Search](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/search.html) on e.g., "*survival frailty*".

Comment: Thank  you for the suggestion; from this resource it appears `frailtypack` is the highest scoring package for survival frailty modelling. I had attempted to use this package but struggling to understand it or get it to work properly as the implementation seems very different to what the text book did. In particular you seem to have to specify a number of knot points and smoother values which seem to greatly impact the results (which I'm not sure how to use to re-create the above numbers).

Comment: There is [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v047i04) and [this paper](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v081i03) from the Journal of Statistical Software which may help you.

Comment: Thank you; will take a look and see if I can use these to solve my problem

Comment: The first paper is likeli the most relevant to you. Though, as far as I recall the packaged is about _correlated survival data_ whereas your problem only involves an individual frailty if I understand your problem correctly? I am not sure whether you can fit such a model with any of the functions in `frailtypack`.

Comment: E.g., the _nested frailty model_ is what you want but without the shared $v_i$ effect on page 3.